# How can I draw the function $f(x) = [\sin x]$ where $|x| \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I draw the function $f(x) = [\sin x]$ where $|x| \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$?

I am confused between the floor function and the $\sin x$ function, it is not clear for me what is the shape of the drawing, could anyone help me please?

Comment: Do you actually want $[\sin x]$ or $\lfloor \sin x \rfloor$?

Comment: And what’s the problem now? Can you explain it a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

We know that

$-1\leq\sin x<0$ for $-\frac{\pi}2\leq x <0$, while

$0\leq \sin x <1$ for $0\leq x<\frac{\pi}2$, and,

$\sin \frac\pi2 =1$

So we have

$$\lfloor\sin x \rfloor=\begin{cases}
-1,&-\frac\pi2\leq x <0\\
0,&0\leq x<\frac\pi2\\
1, &x=\frac\pi2\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that:

- at $x = -\frac{\pi}{2}, \lfloor \sin x \rfloor = -1$.
- in the range: $-\frac{\pi}{2} < x < 0, \sin x < 0 \implies \lfloor \sin x \rfloor = -1$.
- in the range: $0< x < \frac{\pi}{2}, 0 < \sin x < 1 \implies \lfloor \sin x \rfloor = 0$.
- at $x = \frac{\pi}{2}, \lfloor \sin x \rfloor = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$ [ \sin x] = 0 $ for $ 0 \le x < \pi /2$, $-1$ when $  -\pi/2 \le x < 0 $   and $1$ when $ x= \pi/2$.

So the graph from the left is just the line $y=-1$  when $  -\pi/2 \le x < 0 $. then $ y= 0$ when $ 0 \le  x < \pi/2$ and a point $ (\pi/2,1)$.